# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I have used **create-react-app** for my project. I am getting an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

The error is in this code

```
export const ENGLISH = {
  lang: 'en',
  messages: {
      'nav.translatedMessage': 'Social',
  }
};
```

I tried installing babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-stage-0. Also i included the babel dict/object in package.json as

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
```

I am still getting an error.

[image]

Comment: Remove the `,` after `'nav.translatedMessage': 'Social'`

Comment: @Monasha Already tried that. It did not work. This exact code worked when i did not use create-react-app.

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: @loganfsmyth in a screenshot you see an error is in es.js but it is same with en.js too( the code i have posted above).

Comment: So if you look at the line throwing the error, what module is it? Is it your own code? Is it a node module?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Are you talking about es.js?

Comment: es.js and en.js are inside messages folder which is inside public folder. I am using create-react-app. Inside src folder there is reducer directory with local-reducer.js file. In local-reducer i have used import { English } from '../../public/messages/en'.

Comment: It works if i move the folder messages from public to reducer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got my answer on README.md of create-react-app. There it says

> You may create subdirectories inside `src`. For faster rebuilds, only
>   files inside `src` are processed by Webpack.
>  You need to **put any
>   JS and CSS files inside `src`**, or Webpack won’t see them.

Answer (score -7):

I think its because of the comma

```
export const ENGLISH = {
       lang: 'en',
       messages: {
           'nav.translatedMessage': 'Social'
       }
};
```

Try doing this !

Comment: Trailing commas are fine on array items and object properties on any modern browser.