# How to read variable from JS file present in root folder in a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification

I want to access 'testmsg' variable from notification.js present in public folder.

Here is my notification.js code:

```
let testmsg = "abc";
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  console.log(self);
  console.log(event);
  const data = event.data.json();
  testmsg = data;
  console.log(testmsg);
  console.log('New notification', data);
  console.log(data.body);
  const options = {
    body: data.body,
  }
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options)
  );
})
```

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
import requestIp from 'ip';
import Message from './Message';
import * as testmsgtemp from '../public/notification.js';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = { resp: '', correlationId: '', name: '', correlationIdRes: '', nameRes: '' };
    }

    WriteDataToKafka = async () => {
        console.log(requestIp.address());
        this.setState({ correlationId: uuid() });
        console.log(this.state.name);
        setTimeout(async function () {
            console.log(this.state.correlationId);
            await axios.get(<service URL>, {
                headers: {
                    uuid: this.state.correlationId,
                    deviceid: Message.getP256dh(),
                    auth: Message.getAuth(),
                    endpoint: Message.getEndpoint(),
                    ipAddress: requestIp.address()
                },
                params: {
                    parameter: this.state.name
                }
            });
        }.bind(this), 50);

        setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("variable:::",testmsgtemp.testmsg);
        }, 600);
    }

     /* eslint-disable */
    componentDidMount(){
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("./notfications.js").then(function(registration){
            console.log(registration);
        });
    }

    render() {
         return (

        <div  ref={this.myRef}>
            <input placeholder="Enter Your Name" onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}></input>
            <br/><br/>
            <button onClick={this.WriteDataToKafka}>Call Service</button>
            <p>Hej {this.state.nameRes}!</p>
            <p> Unique ID Generated is: {this.state.correlationId}</p>
            <p> Unique ID Received is: {this.state.correlationIdRes}</p>

        </div>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

Please guide me how to read the testmsg variable in App.js.
I have also run `npm eject` to import notification.js from root folder into src. If the testmsg variable value can be read inside App.js then I can use it to render it in DOM. I'm trying to develop a utility which pushes data to client without client requesting it.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I didnt misunderstand of what you are trying to achieve, 
but I try my best, if you meant you want to access to the public folder reside above the src folder, that is actually used for your browser to download public info such as your ico files, logo and etc, and outside of your index.js/app.js folder that is outside of the react can access. But no worry, there is always other way. You can create another data file, inside your src and access it, and build into the bundle.

If you are trying to achieve smaller build bundle, you can use code spliting with react.lazy(). Where webpack will split the bundle into a few for smaller size (faster download)

if it is not the public folder above the src folder you meant... then you can simply doing the import/export:

eg:

notification.js code:

`export default testmsg = "abc";`

In your App.js

`import testmsg from '../public/notification.js';`

or

```
const testmsg = 'abc'
const exportObject = {testmsg}
export default exportObject;
```

In your App.js then

```
import {testmsg} from '../public/notification.js';
```

then just use `console.log(testmsg); //abc`

Comment: I am getting below error on browser

` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' ` on notification.js

Comment: Probably you are exporting from the public folder outside of `src`. see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756359/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export

Comment: You may create subdirectories inside src. For faster rebuilds, only files inside src are processed by Webpack.
You need to put any JS and CSS files inside src, or Webpack won’t see them. README.md of create-react-app

Comment: if that is the case, create a public or any name inside or src folder. then import it like this `import testmsg from './public/notification.js'` depending on how you export it.

Comment: thanks but I have tried these options and it doesn't work. If there is any way that I can listen to push events inside src folder then please let me know.

Comment: Erm... I dont really understand, what do you mean by push event. Do you mean get data from server? ajax. Or the web browser push notification eg: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox